Does the double origin plane have a cut point?
Let the double origin plane consist of the set of points of the plane $\mathbb R^{2}$ together with an additional point $O^{\ast}$. Neighborhoods of points other than the origin $O$ and the point $O^{\ast}$ are the usual open sets of $\mathbb R^{2} \setminus \{O\}$; as a basis of neighborhoods of $O$ and $O^{\ast}$, we take $V_{n}(O) = \{\langle x,y\rangle:x^{2} + y^{2} < \frac{1}{n^2}, y > 0\} \cup \{O\}$ and $V_{n}(O^{\ast}) = \{\langle x,y\rangle:x^{2} + y^{2} < \frac{1}{n^2}, y < 0\} \cup \{O^{\ast}\}$.
Note that this space is (arc) connected. Does this space have a cut point, that is, a point whose removal disconnects the space? This is currently unknown to π-Base.

One quick way to see the result: let $F$ be any finite subset of $X$, and consider these subsets of $X$:

$A=\left(\{O\}\cup\{\langle x,y\rangle:y>|x|\}\right)\setminus F$
$B=\left(\{O^*\}\cup\{\langle x,y\rangle:y<-|x|\}\right)\setminus F$
$C=X\setminus(\{O,O^*\}\cup F)$

These are each copies of (arc) connected subspaces of the Euclidean plane, with $A\cup B\cup C=X\setminus F$, $A\cap C\not=\emptyset$, and $B\cap C\not=\emptyset$. It follows that $X\setminus F$ is (arc) connected.
Therefore no point of $X$ is a cut point.

Hmm, why do you keep talking about arc connected and not path connected? And why talk about removing multiple points and not a single point?

Arc connected is stronger so I'm going ahead and proving something stronger. Same with removing multiple points. Of course, one could just prove the space is connected even after the removal of a single point and avoid arcs/paths altogether: it would be the union of two overlapping connected subspaces of $\mathbb R^2$

Yeah, the desired result is kind of trivial, due to that last observation.

I should add it to my answer as it's much slicker than pasting together arcs, though I'll leave the stronger result in case it's helpful for posterity.

Actually the slick argument (assuming you believe the results for the subspaces of the Euclidean plane) immediately works for arc connectedness as well, so I've switched to just use that instead of explicitly constructing arcs.

EDIT: Hopefully this is enough detail. Still a bit hand-wavey
Let $X$ be the double origin plane. Let $p$ be any point in $X$. Let $a,b$ be any points in $X\setminus \{p\}$. Let $\gamma$ be a path from $a$ to $b$ in $X$. We know that $\gamma$ exists as $X$ is path connected. If $\gamma$ doesn't go through $p$ then we're done. Suppose that $\gamma$ goes through $p$.
Case 1: p is the origin $0$.
WLOG suppose that $\gamma(0.5)=p$. We can create a path $\gamma'$ that avoids $p$ by letting $\gamma'(0.5)=$ the point $0^*$.
Case 2: p is the point $0^*$.
This is nearly identical to case 1, swap $0$ and $0^*$.
Case 3: p is neither the origin $0$ nor the point $0^*$.
WLOG suppose that $\gamma(0.5)=p$. We can create a path $\gamma'$ that avoids $p$, by creating a path $\alpha$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ from $\gamma(0.5-\epsilon)$ to $\gamma(0.5-\epsilon)$ and appropriately concatenate the two pieces of $\gamma$ with $\alpha$ to create $\gamma'$.
This shows that $X$ is path connected.

Review the definition more closely: the neighborhoods of the doubled point aren't the same as those of the Euclidean plane, but I believe you are correct that the result is connected.

This is sloppy and unnecessarily complicated. Just use concatenations of pairs of straight line paths.

My apologies. I'm thinking in a very general and proof sketching way. It would seem to me that given any base space $X$ where $X$ has no cut-points and is path connected necessarily implies that a similarly defined $X \cup {0^*}$ also lacks any cut points. The notion of a straight line doesn't help in for example $\mathbb{Q}^2$. I'm rather new to stack exchange, and would like constructive feedback. Should I edit my answer to be more narrow to the specific question, or does my answer need more detail?

@gilgamesh I'm not certain, but I think from your post you may be under the impression that $X$ is a 2D analog of the line with two origins. This space is not really an analog of that. Note that $X \backslash {0^\ast}$ "looks like" $\mathbb{R}^2$ with a slit just to the south of $0$. I.e., continuous paths leaving the origin must travel within the upper half plane for a short time. And $X$ "looks like" this with an extra origin which is slitted on its north side in this way.

... This $X$ is both non-locally Euclidean and Hausdorff. So it's really not an analog of the line with two origins. (I did not downvote your post.)

@GeoffreySangston That was my initial reaction and I hastily gave an incorrect answer claiming that $X\setminus{0}$ is $\mathbb{R}^2$ which it is not. I've edited my post to remove that from my answer. I believe if we think about paths we can leverage the fact that $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus {0} \subset X \setminus {p}$ to get any path we want. So if you need your path to go through the origin the you can swap to $0^*$ instead. This seems preferable than to completely avoid the origin as there likely is a similar pathological construction where going through the origin is necessary.
